# TensorFlow - NameError: name 'session' is not defined

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm having an error in the last line of the following code portion:

```
confusionMatrix = tf.confusion_matrix(labels=y_true_cls,predictions=y_pred_cls)
x_batch, y_batch, _, cls_batch = data.valid.next_batch(batch_size_validation)
confusionMatrix = session.run(confusionMatrix, feed_dict={x: x_batch, y_true: y_batch})
```

The error states the following:

```
NameError: name 'session' is not defined
```

At the end of my code (after the above code portion), I have the following:

```
with tf.Session() as session:
    init = tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.local_variables_initializer())
    session.run(init)
    train( num_iteration=1000)
```

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: `session` can only be used within the `with` block...

Answer (score 2):

You haven't defined **session** prior to `session.run()` . Simply define it (for example `session=tf.Session()`) and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

I simply included my confusion matrix in a function called `evaluate()`, and issued a call to `evaluate()` under `train(num_iteration=1000)` in the `with tf.Session() as session:` block:

```
with tf.Session() as session:
    init = tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.local_variables_initializer())
    session.run(init)
    train(num_iteration=10000)
    evaluate()
```